# PHPExcel reading too slow

Tags: php, performance, phpexcel

I know, there are lot's of questions here sbout improving `PHPExcel` performance. But all of them are about *writing* data, and my problem is in *reading*.

My function:

```
function parse($filename){
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename); 
    $activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $parsedData = array();
    $columnHeaders = array('order', 'ts', 'summ', 'name', 'quant', 'price', 'bccu');
    foreach ($activeSheet->getRowIterator() as $rkey => $row) {
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        foreach ($cellIterator  as $ckey => $cell) {
            $parsedData[$columnHeaders[$ckey]] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
        }
    }
    return $parsedData;
}
```

The file contains ~300 rows and 7 columns. And this script fails to run in 30 seconds.

How can i improve it?

**edit:**

used

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007");
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);
```

whth no success

Comment: Can you identify if it's the load that's taking the time? or if it's iterating the rows and cells?

Comment: iterating. it only gets to 178th in allowed 30 seconds.

Comment: The iterators are fairly slow, I don't generally use them myself: you might find it more efficient to use the toArray() or rangeToArray() methods, and then walk the resulting array to set the "keys" to the associative names that you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your columns are already defined, what about remove the column iterator?

Try something like this:

```
foreach ($activeSheet->getRowIterator() as $rkey => $row) {
    $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex ();
    $parsedData[$rowIndex]['order'] = $activeSheet->getCell('A' . $rowIndex);
    $parsedData[$rowIndex]['ts']    = $activeSheet->getCell('B' . $rowIndex);
    $parsedData[$rowIndex]['summ']  = $activeSheet->getCell('C' . $rowIndex);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: thanks! worked for me! btw: `PHPExcel_Worksheet->cellExists` was called **100670** times, so i guess cell iterator is realy a bad idea.

Comment: AFAIK, cell iterator's max value is the right most cell that contain values. In your case, maybe there is a cell in column 100670 that has value. Maybe someone accidentally fill it.

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling the garbage collector before running parse() by issuing `gc_disable()`.  Guessing that levels of iterations here don't get optimized properly by PHP.

Comment: checked it now: what i've got was only little more memory consumption :)

Comment: In my case, just reading 250 lines and 10 cols. It boost from 12 sec. to 6 sec.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not going to change the file's contents; setting the reader to read-only gives about 10x boost.

For example:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader( 'Excel5' );
$objReader->setReadDataOnly( true );
```